# What is a good stop criterion when using an iterative method to find eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigensystem, iterative-method

I read [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/585/81) answer, and realized I have been using the difference between sucessive iterates to define a stop criterion for an iterative method of finding eigenvalues/vectors.

**What are good stop criteria for iterative methods that converge to eigenvalues and eigenvectors?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Youssef Saad's book [*Numerical Methods for Large Eigenvalue Problems, 2nd edition*](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/eig_book_2ndEd.pdf) uses the norm of the residual vector to define convergence criteria. He defines the residual vector as follows on page 59:

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, a putative eigenvalue $\widetilde{\lambda} \in \mathbb{C}$ and a putative eigenvector $\widetilde{\mathbf{u}} \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ associated with $\widetilde{\lambda}$, the residual vector $\mathbf{r}$ associated with the pair $(\widetilde{\lambda}, \widetilde{\mathbf{u}})$ is

$$\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{A}\widetilde{\mathbf{u}} - \widetilde{\lambda}\widetilde{\mathbf{u}}.$$

Many of the error results in Saad's book are stated in terms of the norm of the residual vector (generally the 2-norm), and he uses the norm of the residual vector as a metric for convergence whenever he presents numerical results. Based on that evidence, the stopping criterion would be

$$\|\mathbf{r}\| < \varepsilon.$$

[SLEPc](http://www.grycap.upv.es/slepc/) (based on [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/)), appears to use a similar convergence criterion in their [hands-on exercises](http://www.grycap.upv.es/slepc/handson/) (they use $\|\mathbf{r}\|/\|\widetilde{\lambda}\widetilde{\mathbf{u}}\|$ in Exercises 1 and 2 instead).

However, [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) does not necessarily use that metric for convergence (see for instance, in [LAPACK working note (LAWN) #15](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn15.pdf), using Jacobi's method for calculating eigenvectors and eigenvalues of symmetric positive definite matrices). The [LAWNs](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawns/) are rather dense (pardon the pun) and technical, but if you're interested in seeing what high-quality implementations use for convergence, perhaps they're worth a detailed read.

Comment: From what I understand, for linear systems $Ax=b$, if $A$ is ill-conditioned, the residual can much smaller than the actual error of the solution vector $x$.  Is the same true for eigenvalue problems?  If so, what can we do to ensure that $u$ and $\lambda$ in our case are reasonably converged when the residual is small?